# When I run npm list , it shows two versions and I want to delete one version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-router, frontend

npm list react-router

```
├─┬ react-router-config@5.1.1
│ └── react-router@6.2.1
└─┬ react-router-dom@5.2.1
  └── react-router@5.2.1
```

If you look at react-router list, react-router@6.2.1 is downloaded under react-router-config@5.1.1 version.

I tried deleting react-router@6.2.1 in package-lock.json and doing a list.
react-router@6.2.1 keeps outputting.

So I replaced it with react-router-config 5.1.1 -> 5.0.1 .
And I tried npm list react-router, but it comes out the same.

```
├─┬ react-router-config@5.1.1
│ └── react-router@6.2.1
└─┬ react-router-dom@5.2.1
  └── react-router@5.2.1
```

I deleted the 5.1.1 version of react-router-config and installed the 5.0.0 version, but I don't know if the 5.1.1 version still comes out.
And react-router@6.2.1 in the react-router-config list is not deleted either.
How to delete react-

Delete react-router-config@5.1.1 version, change the version to @5.1.0, and run npm list react-router to get the same result.

```
├─┬ react-router-config@5.1.1
│ └── react-router@6.2.1
└─┬ react-router-dom@5.2.1
  └── react-router@5.2.1
```

If you use route 6, you need to migrate, so you can't migrate now.
How do I delete that version 6?

Install react-router-config as 5.1.0, delete lock and node_module, and then run npm install to get the same result.

```
├─┬ react-router-config@5.1.1
│ └── react-router@6.2.1
└─┬ react-router-dom@5.2.1
  └── react-router@5.2.1
```

Comment: you want `npm uninstall react-router@6.2.1`? Is `react-router@6.2.1` in your package.json

Comment: `react-router-config` seems to be an older project, but it seems to not exist anymore in the `react-router-dom` ecosystem, or rather, it seems to install whatever the latest `react-router-dom` version is. Do you even need it though? What are you using from it that you don't get from `react-router-dom` v5 alone?